# What does Stack Exchange use for running background tasks and jobs?

Tags: discussion

Curious what solution Stack Exchange uses for running background tasks, considering they are running many databases and domains, and scale across many machines. Generally that makes windows services relics of the past, if you need to scale job processing over many boxes across many databases.

Can anyone at SE shed light on how they program these background tasks? Originally Jeff blogged about using cache invalidation events as mechanisms for scheduling jobs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We use a windows service that kicks off various HTTP endpoints that run the actual tasks. So the tasks themselves run on pre-defined web servers and are triggered by a windows service on another box.

Comment: Sooo... curl and cron jobs, only Windows style?  I feel validated, somehow...

Comment: yeah .. exactly

Comment: thank you, I agree with charles, it's how I've been doing it. With a lot of strange looks from others. But we know how to redeploy websites quickly, and debug them.