# Very unusual number of users logged into the chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

The C++ lounge used to have ~30 users logged in at a well visited day during the week. [When I noticed this morning](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=4004684#4004684), it was >70 users, [now it's >80](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=4006583#4006583).

When I look at the [list of rooms](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms?tab=all), there's two other rooms who have an incredible amount of logged-in users, which seems really fishy.

Has there been a recent change in what users are displayed as logged in?

Comment: There's been two 'incidents' linked to chat discussed here in the last few days, this might just be an artifact of people going to chat to see the fireworks and subsequently sticking around. I noticed it too.

Comment: @TimPost we can have fireworks?

Comment: @Tim: Sorry, but I fail to see  that this could triple the number of users for hours. Also: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/987515#987515

Comment: @sbi Ah alright. I actually noticed it last night (it wasn't that high, but it was climbing) and didn't think much of it because of the meta activity around certain rooms. Glad to see it's being fixed.

Comment: @Tim: Oh, indeed, we're down to 35 users.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Type a regular expression that looks like it's written to consume HTML in any chat.so room, instant fireworks :)

Comment: Ah, that one. Was expecting some with more colors. And sound.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: The true sign of a spoiled child...

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Ah, no - can't do that. People in chat are dangerous enough while shooting nouns at each other. I cringe when thinking what they'd do with bottle rockets.

Comment: Lounge<C++> is pretty scintillating.  I'd attribute it to an uptick in interest? =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Our [Scheduled Task service](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129063/what-does-stack-exchange-use-for-running-background-tasks-and-jobs/129768#129768) crashed last night. We're not sure yet why, but at least the cryptic Windows crash report has this helpful thing to say:

```
FriendlyEventName=Stopped working
```

Yeah, thanks.

Anyway, one of the scheduled tasks regularly checks for users who have stopped watching a chat room, but are still counted as "in the room". In other words, they closed the browser tab, but didn't explicitly leave. These users are then auto-removed.

Because this didn't happen since the scheduler crash, no one was auto-kicked in the last 13 hours, causing lots of ghosts to wander around in the rooms.

Comment: There should be a ghost buster badge! ;)

Comment: Hey, that's better then the `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The operation completed successfully` exception. At least it tells you that it did not work. ;)

Comment: @GardenGnobobby Maybe Microsoft thinks there is something wrong, if an operation was successfully completed, on Windows. `;)`